# Swift: Thread 1: signal SIGABRT ( get child of AnyObject )

Tags: arrays, swift, anyobject

My code:

```
let userData = result["user"] as? AnyObject // { test="x"; id=0; phone="none" }

var id = Int(userData?["id"] as? String ?? String(userData?["id"] as? String ?? "0"))!
```

After compile i get this error :

> 2018-07-16 18:21:02.747944+0430 Matap[1550:415553] -[__NSCFNumber
>   length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003
>   2018-07-16 18:21:02.748116+0430 Matap[1550:415553] *** Terminating app
>   due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
>   0xb000000000000003'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x183c82d8c 0x182e3c5ec 0x183c90098 0x183c885c8 0x183b6e41c 0x105d9d5f4 0x105d36c68 0x106384478
>   0x1020a4aa0 0x10209f6cc 0x10208ac00 0x10676d1dc 0x10676d19c
>   0x106771d2c 0x183c2b070 0x183c28bc8 0x183b48da8 0x185b2d020
>   0x18db65758 0x1020c9098 0x1835d9fc0) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: `-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector` That's a well known error. At some point, you think that you are using a String object, but it's in fact a `NSNumber` one. Why do you do twice `userData?["id"] as? String`? Parenthesis issue? Instead, some testing that much in one line, do it step by step, line by line with if/else, then find which one is causing the issue?

Comment: I cannot reproduce the same crash with your code. Are you sure the crash happens on any of the lines you have shown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `result["user"]` is not `AnyObject`, according to the output it's clearly a dictionary (`[String:Any]`)
- `userData["id"]` is an `Int`

The error occurs because you treat the number as String.

One-liners seem to be cool but sometimes it's preferable to use a few lines more for better readability

```
let id : Int
if let user = result["user"] as? [String:Any], userId = user["id"] as? Int {
    id = userId
} else {
    id = 0
}
```

And for sake of coolness this is the one-liner

```
let id = (result["user"] as? [String:Any])?["id"] as? Int ?? 0
```

Comment: won't make difference if he casted it to **AnyObject**

Comment: @Sh_Khan It does make a difference. A cast to `AnyObject` bridges to the Objective-C runtime which is completely unnecessary in this case. An obvious JSON object is `Any` in Swift, but you are encouraged to always cast down the object to the most specific type.

Comment: I mean in result not in  better approach

Comment: @Sh_Khan For me *better approach* has always higher priority over just *result* 

Answer (score 0):

id is `NSNumber`

```
var id =  (userData?["id"] as! NSNumber).stringValue // seems you consider it a string
```

Comment: I get this error again : `2018-07-16 19:16:12.554696+0430 Matap[733:234358] -[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003
2018-07-16 19:16:12.556471+0430 Matap[733:234358] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000000003'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x182bd2d8c 0x181d8c5ec 0x182be0098)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException`